# How to put a column of data into list in c#

Tags: c#, list, text

I would like some guidence for c# windows form application to be able to put a full column of numbers into a list, the data will be a text base so for example it will contain 4 columns like this:

```
100 200 300 400
100 200 300 400
101 292 83  7312
```

I can put the entire text into a list but I want to have 4 different list and put each column into its own list if that makes sence.

Would I have to read each line and some how put a split then add to the list?

Ps. I don't expect the Code just maybe the best method of Been able to do this and if am on the right track ?

Comment: If those columns are related, why not store them in a datatable?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you reading in the text from a file, a UI control?

Comment: I wanted to use a list so I can use them for further functions like total columns ect and its from a file so am using stream reader. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't read the values into separate lists.  If you maintain separate lists you'll need to worry about keeping all of the lists synchronized.  I would create an object that you can use to hold all of the information from one line.

```
public class Entry
{
    // give meaningful names to the column values
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    public int Column2 { get; set; }
    public int Column3 { get; set; }
    public int Column4 { get; set; }

    // overriden to make re-constructing the line for the file easier
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // assuming tab as the delimiter, replace with whatever you're using
        return string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", this.Column1, this.Column2,
            this.Column3, this.Column4);
    }
}
```

Then when you read in the values you can do:

```
var entries = new List<Entry>();

using (var fStream = File.OpenRead(fileLocation))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fStream))
{
    while (!reader.EOF)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();

        // assuming tab as the delimiter, replace with whatever you're using
        var parts = line.Split('\t');

        if (parts.Length != 4)
        {
            // whatever you need to do for error handling
            // you could throw an error or just skip to the next line
            continue;
        }

        entries.Add(
            new Entry
            {
                // ideally you'd use int.TryParse to provide further error handling
                Column1 = int.Parse(parts[0]),
                Column2 = int.Parse(parts[1]),
                Column3 = int.Parse(parts[2]),
                Column4 = int.Parse(parts[4])
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Then if you need to interact with just one column value you can use LINQ to query for just the values you need

```
var column1Values = from entry in entries
                    select entry.Column1;
```

Comment: Wow that's very helpful, I wasn't expecting that much help :) I will try this way and see how I get on, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Personally I like `File.ReadAllLines(@"yourTxtFile")`. It makes the code simple in my opinion.

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"yourTxtFile"))
{
   // split and add to the respective lists here
}
```

Comment: I am glad am on right track :).I have code sumular to this already, and from this I can add each line in to the list I am struggling to add each column to separate list so list1 containing column 1 data and so on until their is 4 list for each column of data if that makes sense sorry its not correct terminology